# How to set the data type of a function parameter in python?

Tags: python

```
def recursiveSum(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        #print(str(type(lst))+'\n')    
        num = lst[len(lst)-1]
        return recursiveSum(lst.pop()) + num


size = int(input("How many number do you want to enter? = "))
lst=[]
for i in range(size):
    lst.append(input("Enter number "+str(i+1)+" = " ))
print(recursiveSum(lst))
```

In this code i am trying to find sum of list of numbers recursively , this is my first attempt with recursions , i think my approach and algorithm was correct , the list when passed to the **recursiveSum()** function somehow makes it string in the **else** part , the commented line when executed ends up printing

> class 'list'
>
> class 'str'

I don't understand how the print statement prints both **list** and **str**.

Can someone explain this ?

Comment: because your input is a list of strings - not of numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

- you do not convert your inputs into numerics/integers
- you recurse using the popped element not the remaining list

Fix:

```
def recursiveSum(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        num = lst[0]   # use the first one 
        return recursiveSum(lst[1:]) + num   # and recurse on the remaining slice


size = int(input("How many number do you want to enter? = "))
lst=[]
for i in range(size):
    lst.append(int(input("Enter number "+str(i+1)+" = " )))
print(recursiveSum(lst))
```

`list.pop()` returns the element popped from the list - not the list-remainder.

Answer (score 3):

I think you forgot to type cast to int when input:

```
lst.append(int(input("Enter number "+str(i+1)+" = " )))
```

Comment: Besided: `lst.pop()` returns the last element of `lst`, **not** the list without last element; and `lst[len(lst)-1]` can be more elegantly written as `lst[-1]`